# Element in ring of integers of $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}_p$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, local-field, local-rings

Is it true that every element $x \in \mathcal{O}_{\overline{\mathbb{Q}}_p}$ can be written as $x=u \cdot p^{m/p^s}$ where $u$ is a unit, $m \in \mathbb{N}$ and $s \in \mathbb{N}$?

Note that $p$ is a uniformizer of $\mathbb{Z}_p$, every element $x \in \mathbb{Z}_p$ can be written as $x= u \cdot p^m$ with $u$ is a unit of $\mathbb{Z}_p$. My question is whether every element in the ring of integers of the algebraic closure $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}_p$  can be expressed in term of some $p$-power root of $p$?

Comment: No it is $x= u p^{m/n}$ where $v(x)=\frac{m}{n} v(p)$  (try with $p=2,x=2^{1/3}$)

Comment: Just to make reuns' counter-example more visible, how would you write all $p^{1/n}$ where $n$ is *not* a $p$-power? (Even if one ignores the issue that such roots of $p$ are not uniquely defined in general. They are up to units, of course.)